# Accessing Inner Text Anchor Tag with Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to iterate a table and access the values via XPath,
for example:

```
/html/body/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[10]/span/a
/html/body/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[4]/td[10]/span/a
/html/body/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[10]/span/a
/html/body/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[...]/td[10]/span/a
```

the values contained in the inner html of an anchor tag:

```
    <td>
     <span id="TUFLMTU1MA%3D%3D">
      <a onclick="return false" target="_top" href="">VALUE I WANT</a>
     </span>
    </td>
```

I've tried the Xpath statement which normally works except when using a hyperlink. I can't do it with the id attribute because they are all dynamic. The text I am trying to grab is "VALUE I WANT" above. Also, "VALUE I WANT" changes throughout the table, so I can't just go based on that because it is not that same value everytime.

I am using Selenium RC not the web driver.

Comment: I am just wondering: why are you using [tag:selenium-rc], a technology that has been deprecated for several years now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your xpath in 'for' loop and iterate it as many times as you have elements

```
for(int x = 1; x < your_neumber_of_elements; x++) {
  WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[" + x + "]/td[10]/span/a"));
  Syste.out.println(e.getText());
}
```